# Paramiko/Netmiko - Need to establish an SSH session to run some commands, exit the session, then reconnect to send more commands. Is it possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, paramiko, netmiko

I have a bunch of linux servers that I need to send some configuration commands to and exit the SSH session upon saving in order to reset the services on them. I have this code working for the most part and it will successfully make the changes I want it to make, but I also want it to go back in and run another set of validation commands (for logging purposes) and it won't run anything after the save command. I was wondering if it was possible to re-establish a previous SSH session here to continue running another set of commands. See my code below:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname', username='username', password='password')



stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("""COMMAND1
                  COMMAND2
                  COMMAND3
                  nohup SAVECOMMAND & exit
                  NEXTCOMMANDS""")

for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)

ssh.close()
```

Comment: Note that you can run multiple sessions over one transport, so you don't really need to _disconnect_ to get a new shell at all.

Comment: ...that said, once you've told a shell to exit, no, you can't get it back; instead, you need to start a _new_ `exec_command` instance to get a new shell -- but again, so you can do that over the existing transport, so you don't need to reconnect/reauthenticate. Paramiko gives you some helpers that obscure the transport layer, but they're strictly optional sugar. In this case, you can _and should_ be working with a `Transport` object.

Comment: Once you `exit`, you no longer have a shell, and probably not a session, either.  You need to start a new session to execute more commands.

Comment: ...as another note: As long as you know the remote shell is bash (or otherwise supports the `disown` command) there's almost never a good reason to use `nohup`, as bash can do everything `nohup` does built-in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how would I run multiple sessions in this application? The main reason we are using `nohup` in this manner is because the 'save' command restarts the SSH service on the remote end, so the SSH session would get torn down regardless of the method of delivery.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the SSH session is torn down if you don't have your process attached to the terminal, and you don't need nohup to avoid it being attached. Instead, use `SAVECOMMAND </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & detach -h "$!"` (granted, this _does_ assume you know the shell to be bash, but if it's not, you may not _need_ the detach; it's the redirections that do most of the work, because they ensure stdin stdout and stderr aren't tied to the SSH session's streams).

Comment: As for how to run multiple sessions... I already gave you a pointer; read the paramiko Transport API.

Comment: See in particular [`Transport.connect()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.connect1) &c. Once you have a transport, you can open multiple channels over it.